# How to separate mongodb databases for production and development, both running on one server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, passenger, development-environment, production-environment

I have two (same) rails applications with nginx configs (to use with passenger):

```
> cat ./sites-available/app-production

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app-development.mydomain.com;
  root /path/to/my/production/app/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;
}

> cat ./sites-available/app-development

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app-development.mydomain.com;
  root /path/to/my/development/app/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env development;
}
```

And both have a `./config/mongoid.yml:`

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app-development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:

production:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: app-production
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
```

But if I start both of them I see they use the same db: I change some data in `development` and I see the changes in the `production` as well.

What are the other configurations if these are not enough. Or do I something wrong?

## Update:

actually I don't see if the applications running in different environments. The debug (error) view is rendered by both, if I stop the mongodb. Looks like they both running development. How to force the passenger to run them different environments? I thought this job is done by setting the `rails_env` parameter

## Update 2:

So if I look into `mongo`:

```
> show dbs

  app-development    0.203125GB
  local (empty)
```

So, the production db is not created.

## Update 3:

I also executed:

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

in my production rails app, but still no effect.

## Update 4:

as proposed here [Can't force Rails into production environment via Passenger/Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983692/cant-force-rails-into-production-environment-via-passenger-nginx?rq=1) I removed `config.ru`, but then I get an error from `Phusion Passenger`:

```
This application is a Rails 4 application, but it was wrongly detected as a Rails 1 or Rails 2 application. This is probably a bug in Phusion Passenger, so please report it.
```

## Update 5:

now (after I returned the config.ru back) it became even worse - error from `Phusion Passenger`:

```
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

I do `bundle install` and no effect.

## Update 6:

from here [is not checked out... bundle install does NOT fix help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help)

```
bundle install --deployment
```

now install all the gems. No `Phusion Passenger` errors anymore, but I get now an error from `rails`:

```
Permission denied - /path/to/my_rails_app/tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/37b5a12047376b10a57191a10d3af30a rails error
```

And I have no such file/folders behind the `./tmp/`

## Update 7:

Sounds like the similar problem here [Permission denied in tmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524262/permission-denied-in-tmp) . But I don't know which `chown user:group` I should apply? I have `Phusion Passenger` and `nginx`.

If I execute:

```
> sudo chown -R http:http ~/project/my_app/
```

I get:

```
chown: invalid user: `http:http'
```